# How to unzip bigger zip on Android?

Tags: android, performance, unzip, zipinputstream

I unzip files in my Android Studio project like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html):

```
 InputStream is = ...
 ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
 try {
     ZipEntry ze;
     while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
         int count;
         while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
             baos.write(buffer, 0, count);
         }
         String filename = ze.getName();
         byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
         // do something with 'filename' and 'bytes'...
     }
 } finally {
     zis.close();
 }
```

The original zip file is approx. 30 MB big and contains just *.txt files. Two of those text files are > 100 MB, so that I get this error message:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:  main Process: com.example.myapp,
>   PID: 15821        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a
>   167083628 byte allocation with 33542384 free bytes and 136MB until OOM
>         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.expand(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:91)
>         at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:201)
>         at com.example.myapp.managers.UnzipManager.decompressZip(UnzipManager.java:104)
>         at com.example.myapp.managers.UnzipManager.(UnzipManager.java:43)
>         at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:103)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

**How can I decompress those files propery?**

Comment: What are you doing with the bytes you have loaded? Why are you using a ByteArrayOutputStream to convert a byte array to another byte array?

Comment: @cyroxis This is an example from Google, see link in my first line.

Comment: Is that your actual code that is having issues?

Comment: @cyroxis Yes, since the decompressed file is bigger than 100 MB, the baos object will increase at that size. I've heard, that each App on android has limited space?

Comment: You will have to write to the file system.